# Compatibility for IE <8 in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there anything I can temporarily cripple Chrome with to make it mimic the IE < 8 non-compliance issues, or are we all doomed forever to actually test in IE8 Compatibly Mode?

Comment: Is installing multiple instances of IE an alternative for you? Instead of cripppling an other browser to behave like an IE, why not using a real one: http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any method to cripple Chrome, but here's a link to a program that can actually let you test in just about any version of IE you could desire

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Hope this helps :)

EDIT: Yeah, you're still using an IE-like browser...but I've found that sometimes Compatibility doesn't catch everything that actual IE8 does. I've had things work just fine in Compatibility, but die horribly in actual IE8

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of problems with using other IE testers, i've tried them all.

What I ended up doing is installing [vmware](http://www.vmware.com/) on my computer to create a virtual computer, installing windows XP on those and made virtual computers for IE6,7, and now 8. I also installed an Ubuntu one so I can test all the open source browsers as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an XP license for a VM, and Virtual Box gives me grief with my Windows 7 OEM disk.

Comment: if that is the case then I suggest you use http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage as guildsbounty pointed out, it was the best of the ones I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give a new response to this question:
http://www.conceivablytech.com/5427/products/just-in-case-you-need-ie6-%E2%80%A6/

Microsoft now offers *free* versions of the past browsers running on XP/Vista to run as a virtual PC on windows 7. This will expire on May 18th though :/